# Spring framework, @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT)

Tags: java, spring, transactions

From the documentation:
[Isolation.DEFAULT](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Isolation.html#DEFAULT)

> > Use the default isolation level of the underlying datastore.

for other isolation levels we can read their limitations in [wiki,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Isolation_Levels_vs_Read_Phenomena)
but what about DEFAULT?  How does it actually behave?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DEFAULT means: don't set any isolation level explicitely, and thus use the isolation level that the database uses by default.

So read the documentation of your database and driver, and see which one it uses by default. Most of the time, it's READ_COMMITTED. But some databases might have another default value.

Comment: thanks, JB!
the whole day i read the Spring docs and my brain exploded :)
so, I asked the question and only after that realized the answer